# How to disable Sendgrid mail relay on Postfix

Tags: email, postfix, ubuntu-16.04, sendgrid

I have a Sendgrid account, and have setup Sendgrid to work with my Postfix mail server. However, I would like to disable Sendgrid as a mail relay. I followed this article to set up: https://serverok.in/postfix-sendgrid

However, I am unsure how to disable Sendgrid. Do I just need to comment out these lines in /etc/postfix/main.cf?

```
 smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
 smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
 smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
 smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
 smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
 header_size_limit = 4096000
 relayhost = [smtp.sendgrid.net]:587
```

After removing, I should just be able to restart postfix for the changes to take effect using the below?

```
 sudo postfix reload
```

Here is my /etc/postfix/main.cf file:

```
  # See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


  # Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
  # line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
  # is /etc/mailname.
  #myorigin = /etc/mailname

  smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
  biff = no

  # appending .domain is the MUA's job.
  append_dot_mydomain = no

  # Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
  #delay_warning_time = 4h

  readme_directory = no

  # TLS parameters
  smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
  smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
  smtpd_use_tls=yes
  smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
  smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

  # See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
  # information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

  smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
  myhostname = [hidden for security]
  alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
  alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
  mydestination = $myhostname, [hostname hidden], localhost.localdomain, , localhost
  relayhost =
  mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
  mailbox_size_limit = 0
  recipient_delimiter = +
  inet_interfaces = loopback-only
  inet_protocols = all

  transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport

  smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
  smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
  smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
  smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
  smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
  header_size_limit = 4096000
  relayhost = [smtp.sendgrid.net]:587

  smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_unknown_client
  disable_vrfy_command = yes
```

I want to be able to disable Sendgrid relay, and still have my postfix mail server functioning and sending emails without issue.

Comment: Comment the `relayhost` line

Comment: got it, so I would just need to comment that line, and run "sudo postfix reload" ?

Comment: Yes. Commenting `smtp_` client lines you isolated is also good.  They are not what redirects the mail, but control authentication at the destination (which you will not be doing if mail is being delivered directly).